# What is “./junk” file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

What is `./junk`  file in PowerShell ? What happened when we send any output to the junk file ?

Comment: That's not a "PowerShell thing"

Comment: You have propably seen this in another question, where it was used to "suppress" output, e. g. `Some-Command > ./junk`. This actually creates a file named "junk" in the current directory! The PowerShell-ish way to truly suppress output is to assign to pseudo-variable `$null` like this: `$null = Some-Command`.

Comment: @zett42 can I send the output to auto-variable `$null` , like `some command > $null` ?

Comment: @SanniddhaChakrabarti Yes, that works as well - assigning to `$null` is usually faster than redirecting though, at least in Windows PowerShell